# How to grep to find a missing line

Tags: grep, text-processing

I have a file with logged HTTP requests in the following way

```
POST pathX 
header1: any
header2: any
header3: CONSTANT

POST pathX 
header1: any
header2: any

POST pathX 
header1: any
header2: any
header3: CONSTANT
...
```

I would like to find all requests which are on path "pathX" and do not contain a header3.
The number of lines with headers can be different per each requests, 
but usually it is 3 or 4.

I can find all requests to pathX and display the next4 lines like

```
cat file | grep "pathX" -A 4
```

this would find all 3 requests but what I am really after is only the second one which does not have the `"header3: CONSTANT"` line.

Comment: If you have a GNU grep, try `grep -Eoz 'pathX\nheader1:.*\nheader2:.*\n\n'`

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky using normal grep regular expressions. However if you have access to a program that supports Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE) such as `pcregrep`, then you can do:

```
pcregrep <file -M '(?s)^POST pathX(?:(?!^header3:).)*?(\n\n|\Z)'
```

- `-M` enables multiline matching
- `(?s)` makes `.` match `\n` so we don't have to write `(\n|.)`
- `(?!^header3:).` matches any character not preceded by `header3:` at the start of a line
- `(?: ... )*?` matches `...` zero or more times, but as few as possible to make the match succeed
- `(\n\n|\Z)` matches empty line or end of file

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk -v RS=  '/pathX/ && !/header3/' file
```

Using your input file, the output is:

```
$ awk -v RS=  '/pathX/ && !/header3/' file
POST pathX 
header1: any
header2: any
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS=`

  This tells awk to use blank lines as the record separator.  This means that each request (POST and headers) are all read in as one record.
- `/pathX/ && !/header3/`

  This tells awk to print any record that contains `pathX` but not `header3`.